# install scipy module on centos

Tags: python, centos, scipy, installation

I'm using centos, and I installed python2.7 alternately to the default python. I'm able to install all the module I want with pip, but I can't install scipy. When I'm doing

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install scipy
```

It's downloading it, but then I have this error message:

```
blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

  libraries  not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

blas_info:

  libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

blas_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py", line 234, in setup_package

    setup(**metadata)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup

    config = configuration()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py", line 173, in configuration

    config.add_subpackage('scipy')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage

    caller_level = 2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage

    caller_level = caller_level + 1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)

  File "scipy/setup.py", line 12, in configuration

    config.add_subpackage('integrate')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage

    caller_level = 2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage

    caller_level = caller_level + 1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)

  File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 12, in configuration

    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 350, in get_info

    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 509, in get_info

    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)

numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-z_rbuN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

any idea how to install it?

Answer (score 47):

Scipy requires two Linear Algebra libraries installed on your system. Make sure the following (or variants thereof) are installed,

```
sudo yum install blas-devel lapack-devel
```

Comment: Thanks! Why this requirement isn't listed anywhere on Scipy's (nor scikit-learn's) websites is a mystery to me. I also edited your answer to include gcc-c++, as that's needed by the scipy install as well (fails after a long time of compiling other stuff before it tells you that). Much obliged.

Comment: @JJC: Thanks for your comment.  I guess your edit was rejected, but gcc-c++ is indeed a requirement.  I've tried to edit the answer as well, hopefully it's accepted this time.

Comment: I've opened an issue and made a pull request to mention this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy.org/issues/159 feel free to improve it or to follow the issue to see when it gets accepted.